# PHP print after fputcsv

Tags: php, fputcsv

I'm having issues printing anything to the PHP page after building a CSV file.

Here is the parsing of input -> array.

```
 <?php 
 if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {
    PrintExcel();
  }
    function PrintExcel() {
    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    global $errors, $invalid_input, $finalassembly, $csv_output, $headers, $filename;
    $input = $_POST['convert'];
    $inputdata = explode("\n", $input);
    $invalid_input = array();
    $csv_output = array();
    $filename = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa") . substr(str_shuffle(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ),0, 1) . substr(str_shuffle  (aBcEeFgHiJkLmNoPqRstUvWxYz0123456789),0, 31);
    $headers = ['Flag'];
    foreach ($inputdata as $key => $val) {

        $value = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n", "\v", "\t", "\0","\x"), " ", $val);
        $pos = substr($value,0, strpos($value, ' '));
        if (preg_match("[\byes\b|\bno\b]", $val) && (preg_match("enter code here[\bCT\b|\bsi\b]", $val) ===1)){
            $usergroup = ",,,,,,,,,,,333/333/xxx/FffffK,";}
        else {
            $invalid_input[] = "Could not map $pos qualifications to any 
            usergroup";
                continue;
            }
        if (!empty($pos) && (!empty($usergroup))) {                           
        $finalassembly = "update,".$pos . $usergroup.",";
        $csv_output[] = $finalassembly; 
       }   else {
        continue; 
        }
    }
    file_put_contents('errors.txt', $invalid_input);
    $recoveredData = file_get_contents('errors.txt');
    $recoveredArray = unserialize($recoveredData);
    print_r($recoveredArray);
    $empty_input = array_filter($csv_output);
    if (!empty($empty_input)) 
        saveCSV();
    }
```

In this function I'm looking for valid input and saving invalid input to an array.. I've tried printing the array, I've tried saving it to a text, then printing it.... but the errors won't print whenever I have ANY valid input data.

When I have valid input data this runs:

```
function saveCSV() {
    global $errors, $finalassembly, $csv_output, $headers, $filename;
    ob_end_clean();
    $file = fopen('php://memory', "w");
      fputcsv($file, $headers);
      foreach ($csv_output as $line)
      {
      fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
      }
      rewind($file);
      $csvFile = stream_get_contents($file);
    fclose($file);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($csvFile));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.csv"');

    exit($csvFile);>?
```

But none of the errors are printed, and I'm unable to print any of the variables.

Any clues as to why I cannot print anything?

I've tried printing them both before and after calling the saveCSV() function.

Comment: your are calling an `exit` in your save, perhaps that has something todo with it

Comment: Welcome. Could the reason be that you `ob_start()` but your `ob_end_clean()`  comes after your output?

Comment: It would be a wonder if your first code snippet worked as expected with these two constants in the shuffling part of `$filename` - but what have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: @sietse85 this seems to be the correct answer, however without the exit(), how can I save it before printing anything else? If I just remove the exit() I'll print everything to the file.

Comment: with saving you mean, saving it on the server? or pushing a download to the browser?

Comment: Pushing it to download. It already does that without the exit function, but when i remove exit() I get all my errors sent to the CSV as well.
I want them printed to the page, not included in the  CSV.

Comment: You need to go read up on some basics of how HTTP works first of all. You can not answer _one_ request with _two_ different responses. You either answer with a CSV file for the browser to download, _or_ stuff to be output as part of an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send header information after sending any other
content

http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

if you want to see the errors comment out the header instructions.

Instead of exit() use a simple echo $csvFile.